# UK citizen living in canada for three years - do i change my address in the UK to canada?

Tags: united-kingdom, canada, relocation

I am a UK citizen living in Canada on a sponsored work permit for three years.  I still have a property in the UK, so should I keep that as my address with banks, credit cards etc or should I update it to my Canadian address for the three years I'm in Canada?
I want to make sure I'm doing the best thing for when I return to the UK and need to get credit, a new mortgage etc.

not sure what the right thing to do is!  thanks for everyone's help in advance!
G

Comment: What is happening to the property in the meantime?  Is it empty? are you letting it out? is a friend/relative living in it?

Comment: thanks for coming back.  we are renting it out - and have informed HMRC and our mortgage company that this is what we are doing. ie it is all above board ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you are *supposed* to do, is to tell all the firms you have dealing with that you are resident in Canada for the next three years.  However, three years doesn't strike me as very long and that is going to be a bureaucratic hassle (some companies might not even let you keep your accounts open).

The important thing is that if someone writes to your address, that the mail gets to you reasonable promptly.

If you know your tenants personally, you could ask them to forward post to you (or possibly to open it and scan it to you).  I wouldn't do that if you don't know them - important stuff may build up over a long period.

Otherwise, do you know anyone in the UK that would be prepared to do that for you (parents, siblings, close friends)?  Changing your address to their (UK) address is probably straightforward and unlikely to cause problems.

In terms of credit on your return, I wouldn't worry too much.  I presume you have a mortgage on the property which you are keeping up with; that should be enough to maintain your credit score.

P.S. If you have a driving license, don't forget to tell DVLC.

Comment: this is great - thanks for the advice.  we already have mail forwarding to a trusted person.  and yes - we gave up our UK driving licence for Canadian ones.  might make hiring a car when we go home to visit more difficult ;)

Comment: @Gemma Any of the airports you fly to from Canada will be very used to foreign passports.  They don't even blink when we hand over our German driving licenses, (although those *are* pretty much identical to UK ones), and I never had a problem with a UK license in the States.